# Usando "UPDATE" en Mysql me crea un nuevo registro en vez de actualizar el que acabo de editar

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo un código para poder editar artículos y que al guardarlos se actualice la base de datos. El código HTML:

```
<form class="articulos" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="editar.php" method="post">

        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $post['ID'] ?>">
        <h1>Título</h1>
        <input type="text" name="titulo" value="<?php echo $post['titulo'] ?>">

        <h1>Publicado por:</h1>
        <select class="select" name="creador">
            <option name="Egoi" value="Egoi" <?php if ($creador == 'Egoi Cantero') {echo 'selected';} ?>>Egoi Cantero</option>
        </select>

        <h1>Categoria:</h1>
        <select class="select" name="categoria">
            <option name="Articulo" value="Articulo" <?php if ($categoria == 'Articulo') {echo 'selected';} ?>>Articulo</option>
            <option name="Analisis" value="Analisis" <?php if ($categoria == 'Analisis') {echo 'selected';} ?>>Análisis</option>
        </select>

        <h1>Artículo</h1>
        <textarea name="articulo"><?php echo $post['articulo'] ?></textarea>

        <input class="fichero" type="file" name="thumb">

        <input class="enviar" type="submit" name="enviar" value="Guardar cambios">


    </form>
```

El código PHP, lo primero que hace es cargar la información a través del ID.

```
   <?php

    $id = $_GET['ID'];

    try {
    $conexion = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=Blog", 'root', '' );
    } catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage;
    die();
    }

    if (isset($_POST['enviar']) AND $conexion) {

    $creador = isset($_GET['creador']) ? $_GET['creador'] : 'Egoi Cantero';
    $categoria = isset($_GET['categoria']) ? $_GET['categoria'] :    'Articulo';

    $titulo = trim($_POST['titulo']);
    $publicado = $creador;
    $id = trim($_POST['ID']);
    $categoria = $categoria;
    $thumb = $_FILES['thumb']['tmp_name'];
    $thumb_db = $_FILES['thumb']['name'];
    $articulo = $_POST['articulo'];

    $ruta = '../imagenes/articulos/' . $thumb_db;

    $statement = $conexion->prepare("UPDATE art SET
        titulo = :titulo,
        thumb = :thumb,
        publicado_por = :publicado,
        categoria = :categoria,
        articulo = :articulo
    WHERE id = $id");

    $statement->execute(array(
        ':titulo' => $titulo,
        ':thumb' => $thumb_db,
        ':publicado' => $publicado,
        ':categoria' => $categoria,
        ':articulo' => $articulo
    ));

    header('panel_control.php');
    echo "hola";


    } else {

    $statement = $conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM art WHERE id = $id");
    $statement->execute();
    $posts = $statement->fetchAll();

    $post = $posts[0];
    $creador = $post['publicado_por'];
    $categoria = $post['categoria'];
    }

    require '../views/editar.view.php';

?>
```

No acabo de encontrar el error. Tampoco me redirígeme a "*panel_control.php*" ni me muestra "hola" en pantalla, que lo he puesto para saber si estaba entrando a esa parte del código.

---

Cambiando la linea de código

```
$id = $_POST['ID'];
```

Por

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
```

El header funciona, es decir me redirige, aunque no se actualiza la entrada en la base de datos.

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52606/discussion-on-question-by-jetlagfox-usando-update-en-mysql-me-crea-un-nuevo-re).

Comment: Por favor, en lugar de editar tu pregunta y agregar "Resuelto" o similares, mejor publica una respuesta.